# Solution of Differential equation $ 4x^2y''+8xy'+y=2xy^3 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find solution of differential equation

$$ 4x^2y''+8xy'+y=2xy^3, \quad y(1)=1, \ y'(1)=0 $$

I see that $ 4x^2y''+8xy' = (4x^2y')' $, but don't know, if it is useful or not

If we divide by $ y^3 $ ($y \equiv 0$  is a solution) we get

$$ 4x^2 \frac{y''}{y^3}+8x \frac{y'}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y^2}=2x $$

I've tried such substitutions:

- $ y=z^{-1/2}: \quad 3x^2 \frac{z'^2}{z}-2x^2z''-4xz'+z = 2x $
- $ y=e^{-z/2}: \quad (-2x^2z''+x^2z'^2-4xz'+1)e^z=2x $
- $ y=tx^{-1/2}: \quad xt''+t'=2x^{-1}t^3 $

For the last one I found answer in parametrical form:

$$ x=C_2 \exp(\int(C_1 \pm \tau^4)^{-1/2} d\tau) $$

$$ y=\frac{\pm \tau}{\sqrt{x}} $$

I understand that these substitutions aren't fully correct and want to find solution in ordinary form

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried?

Comment: @VegetathePrinceofSaiyans ... will variation of parameters really help in a nonlinear differential equation?

Comment: Maple writes the solution using an elliptic function.  So the solution is not an elementary function.  Presumably, when you change variables to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$, you end up with an elliptic integral .

Comment: @GEdgar sorry lol, I didn’t notice that it was a $y^3$. Yeah, VoP won’t help here. This is a nonlinear problem, which makes it interesting already.

Comment: I blame Kakarot he was distracting me being a clown.

Answer (score 2):

We try the substitution $y(x)=\frac{f\! \left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$:

$$4 \left(\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}f\! \left(x\right)\right) x^{2}-2 f\! \left(x\right)^{3}+4 \left(\frac{d}{d x}f\! \left(x\right)\right) x=0$$

Next we substitute $f(x)=g\! \left(\ln\! \left(x\right)\right)$:

$$4 \mathrm{D}^{\left(2\right)}\! \left(g\right)\! \left(\ln\! \left(x\right)\right)-2 g\! \left(\ln\! \left(x\right)\right)^{3}=0$$

Variable change $x=\exp\left(z\right)$ leads to:

$$4 \frac{d^{2}}{d z^{2}}g\! \left(z\right)-2 g\! \left(z\right)^{3}=0$$

The initial conditions $[y(1)=1, y'(1)=0]$ transform to $[g(0)=1, g'(0)=\frac{1}{2}]$

Hence we get the solution $$g\! \left(z\right)=\frac{2}{2-z}$$

$$g(\ln(x))=f(x)=\frac{2}{2-\ln\! \left(x\right)}$$

and finally

$$y(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}\, \left(2-\ln\! \left(x\right)\right)}$$